# Understanding 'getView()'

Tags: java, android

I have an array that I need to access the elements of dependant on which item in a listView has been clicked.

The first int value sent to the getView() method i.e int arg0 is this  the ID of the element of the array that has been clicked? Do I need to assign the ID from a listview onClickListner?

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
}
```

I believe the following two overidden methods must be implemented aswell:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}
```

Currently my app is only allowing me to access element 0 (the first element) of the array so I believe its ignoring the other 19 elements no matter what item in my listview is clicked.

```
private List<GeoName> names = new ArrayList<GeoName>();

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

    GeoName location = this.names.get(arg0);

    Location l = location.getGeometry().getLocation();

    Latt = l.getLat();
    Longg = l.getLng();
```

From the above code, should 'arg0' be automatically assigned the element ID value when the name.get()' method is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every item in your ListView is a view and getView is responsible for creating these views for your Listview. Following is the excerpt from the Android documentation :

```
public abstract View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

**Parameters**
```

> **position:** The position of the item within the adapter's data set of the
>   item whose view we want. 
>     **convertView:**  The old view to reuse, if
>   possible. Note: You should check that this view is non-null and of an
>   appropriate type before using. If it is not possible to convert this
>   view to display the correct data, this method can create a new view.
>   Heterogeneous lists can specify their number of view types, so that
>   this View is always of the right type (see getViewTypeCount() and
>   getItemViewType(int)). 
>     **parent :**  The parent that this view will
>   eventually be attached to

Following is a sample code snippet on how you would implement a listener for your ListView :

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listview_array));
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        ListviewOnclickExample.this);
        adb.setTitle("ListView OnClick");
        adb.setMessage("Selected Item is = "+ lv.getItemAtPosition(position));
        adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
        adb.show();                     
    }
 });
```

I would recommend that you use the ConvertView and ViewHolder style to make your Listview effecient. [Here](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) is a good link that describes how this style works. You can download a complete sample from my implementation of this style [here](https://github.com/asabbarwal/EffecientListViewDesign)

Comment: Many thanks that a very informed answer. That makes the function of the getView much more clear.

Answer (score 0):

getView has nothing to do with clicks.  It gets the view for the Nth position in the list, where N is the first parameter.  It should only be called by the ListView itself, its used by the ListView to initialize its views when scrolled.